# Get available network interfaces for PHP cURL request

Tags: php, curl

I am aware that I can specify a network interface or IP address for outgoing cURL connections using `CURLOPT_INTERFACE` in PHP like this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, '192.168.0.1');
```

Is there a way to programmatically retrieve a list of all the available interfaces that are configured on a server?  Currently I am doing this in bash:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

This is where network interfaces are configured on my Debian based server, but I would like to get this info inside a php script without needing shell access or read permissions to the file mentioned above - and ideally something that works in different server environments.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've set up `/etc/hosts` with appropriate entries, you should be able to get an array of IP addresses like this:

```
 $ips = gethostbynamel(gethostname());
```

On my system, `var_dump($ips)` returns this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "127.0.0.1"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "127.0.0.1"
  [2]=>
  string(15) "192.168.31.14"
}
```

[`gethostbynamel()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php) returns a list of IP addresses, unlike [`gethostbyname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) which just does a simple lookup and returns the first address it finds.

Comment: That's pretty awesome but not quite what I need because I can't necessarily rely on it being configured and configuring it would require sudo privs and shell access.  All the same, I didn't know about `gethostnamebyl()` so thanks for that tip.

Comment: I think about the only other option is using `exec()` or friends to run `ifconfig`, which would also require configuration on the server side to allow it.

Comment: Assuming that `gethostnamebyl()` returns all potentially-available IPs (and doesn't leave any out), then you could, theoretically, run a simple curl request for each one using `CURLOPT_INTERFACE`, and the ones that don't have errors are the ones configured. You'd probably only want to do this once per execution (or even once per day and store the results somewhere like a file or DB).